# Lifting homomorphism in profinite group

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group and all its finite quotients be $G_i$. Let $\phi_i : G \longrightarrow G_i$ be standard map and $\phi_{i,j}: G_j \longrightarrow G_i$ be the standard surjective maps between $G_i$'s (part of inverse system). And let $\psi_i : G 
 \longrightarrow G_i$ be a collection of map such that $\phi_{i,j} \circ \psi_{j} = \psi_i$ for every pair $i, j$, where $\phi_{i,j}$ makes sense. Then how can we lift $\psi_i$ to $\psi: G \longrightarrow G$ such that $\psi \circ \phi_i = \psi_i$? Is it obvious that such $\psi$ will be continuous endomorphism of $G$?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the correct composition should be $\phi_i \circ \psi = \psi_i$. Either way, from what I understand, this follows from the universal property of the inverse limit. In general, if you have an inverse system of profinite groups $\{G_i,\phi_{ij},I\}$ with $G = \varprojlim G_i$ and continuous morphisms $\psi_i \colon H \to G_i$ which are compatible with the $\phi_{ij}$ as you described, then there is an unique continuous morphism $\psi \colon H \to G$ such that $\phi_i \circ \psi = \psi_i$. In your case, we have $H=G$. You may check page 2 of Ribes-Zalesskii for a reference.